# Unexpected navigation tf warning

Tags: navigation, turtlebot2, turtlebot, ros-groovy, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sometimes, while launching the autonomous navigation the following warning occurs :

```
[ WARN] [1372337372.793829100]: Waiting on transform from /base_footprint to /map to becomeavailable before running costmap, tf error:
```

and after that, I can't manage to get the navigation to work again. Most of the times, it does work fine. I don't understand why sometimes it doesn't.

The manipulations I do is launching turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch and then launching the navigation's nodes thanks this launch file :

```
<launch>
  <include file = "$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/3dsensor.lau
nch">
    <arg name = "depth_processing" value = "false" />
  </include>
  <!--Map server-->
  <node name = "map_server" pkg = "map_server" type = "map_serve
r" args = "/maps/my_map.yaml"/>
  <include file = "$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/
_amcl.launch">
    <arg name = "initial_pose_x" value = "16.6"/>
    <arg name = "initial_pose_y" value = "34.55"/>
    <arg name = "initial_pose_a" value = "1.59"/>
  </include>
  <include file = "$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/
_move_base.launch"/>
```

I first thought it was because the nodes which update tf tree needed time to initialize... But I am not sure that is the reason.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66098/unexpected-navigation-tf-warning/) by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2013-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's nothing wrong with your launch file. My guess is that kinect is not working properly when you get this error. When it happens again, can you echo /scan topic? If nothing is coming, check that Kinect is not connected to a USB 3.0 port.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-06-27**:
I just checked : you were right, when it doesn't work /scan topic is empty. But there is no USB 3.0 port on the turtlebot's laptop. But now that I know what is not working, I can try to solve it. Thanks.